# Java stream to compare elements of two lists and find matches

Tags: java, loops, foreach, java-stream

New to java.
I have two lists - the list of customers with all the items in their cart and the master list of items. The following are the example of the two objects

Customer

```
[
{
    "customerId": 123,
    "cartItems": [
        {
            "itemId": "123-XYZ",
            "itemPrice": 200
        }, 
        {
            "itemId": "123-ABC",
            "itemPrice": 100
        }
    ]
},
{
    "customerId": 987,
    "cartItems": [
        {
            "itemId": "987-XYZ",
            "itemPrice": 200
        }
    ]
}
]
```

The itemID in the customer object contains the customer ID and the item name separated by "-".

Master list of items

```
[
    {
        "itemName": "XYZ",
        "itemPrice": 200
    },
    {
        "itemName": "ABC",
        "itemPrice": 100
    }
]
```

I want to compare the two lists and find the customer who has all the items from the master list. The master list is dynamic and can change from time to time.
I am able to execute this using simple for loop with two items in the master list. Kindly suggest if stream function can be used to solve this correctly.

```
for(Customer customer: customers) {
    List<Item> items = customer.getItems();

    for(Item item: items) {
        if(item.getItemId().contains(masterListItems.getItemName()) & item.getItemPrice().equals(masterListItems.getItemPrice()) {
            System.out.println("Item found");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the criterion for a cart item to match a master list item? Are there any matches in your example data?

Comment: The item name in master list should match the name in the itemId and the price should match. There are other attributes in the cart items, but they are not used in comparison. Hence I have not shown them. In the example, the customer ID 123 matches with the master list.

Comment: Ah, so `itemId` is the concatenation of `customerId` and `itemName` with a hyphen in between. I understand why I didn’t see this readily. I recommend you edit your question and explain.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, You can use Java streams to solve this, Try this code in your code :

```
List<Customer> customersWithAllItems = customers.stream()
            .filter(customer -> {
        List<String> customerItemNames = customer.getCartItems().stream()
            .map(item -> item.getItemId().split("-")[1]) 
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
        List<String> masterItemNames = masterListItems.stream()
            .map(Item::getItemName)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
        return masterItemNames.containsAll(customerItemNames);
    })
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Is there anyway to match the price as well?

Comment: As currently implemented, this is unnecessarily super inefficient, since it's creating the `masterItemNames` anew for each customer, and it's doing a linear search over all the master item names for each customer.

This could be sped up by moving the creation of `masterItemNames` outside of the filter and by making it a set.  `Set<String> masterItemNames = masterListItems.stream().map(Item::getItemName).collect(Collectors.toSet()); customers.stream().filter(…).collect(Collectors.toList());`